# htaccess securing files from being accessed by users

Tags: php, css, .htaccess

So, I'm sure this question gets asked quite a lot around here, but after a good 20 mins searching, I haven't been able to find any questions that produce the correct result.

I have files, such as `/index.php` and `/dashboard.php` which use resource files such as `/framework/assets/stylesheets/index.css` etc. What I want to do, is block off the access to any files in the `/framework/` directory, but still allow usage of them from `index.php` and the other respective files. How would I configure my .htaccess file to allow me to do this?

I understand that this may not be possible, but is there any way that the directory `/framework/` which includes some PHP files to be hidden from users, but still allowed to be accessed via other PHP scripts using `include 'file.php'`?

Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: From the severs point of view, including a file in your HTML (<link rel="stylesheet"..., <script src="..., <img src="...) vs enter the full URL to the files in the browser is exactly the same thing. In both cases the files get downloaded to the client so you can't block one way and not the other.

Comment: What you can do is block access to /framework/ in your main.htaccess (the files will still be available throu include/require) and then add a second .htaccess in your /framework/assets/ folder allowing access

Comment: I was expecting this as a response to the resource files. Is there any way to exclude access to PHP files, but allowing for the `include` function to work?

Comment: The include/require functions is not affected by your .htaccess..   .htaccess is a apache-only file and only responds to a http-request.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to have a css file only available when the specific php script is run you could use a include directive in php and embed this into your other html.

Something like this:

```
//...
<head>
    <style>
    <?php
        include("/framework/assets/stylesheets/index.css");
    ?>
    </style>
//...
</head>
//...
```

php-files aren't restricted through htaccess and you include it server side and offer only the stuff you want to the client.

Comment: Could you provide an example or further explanation for this? And documentation about the method you are mentioning?

Comment: I understand where you're coming from, but with general site markup, using the HTML `<link rel='' type='' href=''/>` is better practice.

Comment: You want the css only available when the php-file is accessed. Since this calls it from browser side it can't be blocked otherwise from direct access.

Comment: He, is I, it was to restrict access to the CSS from the address bar. Please excuse if it didn't come across that way.

Comment: Yes, you want it forbidden from the address bar. Since this is client side you can't block it except you embed the css in your webserver response.

Comment: Can't comment yet to your post below, but this is the way you can do it. Although I see no reason in blocking css.

Answer (score 1):

You should't block access to CSS and JavaScript files. If you do so, it means that your site's design is going to break. For include files, try below rules. Place your `.htaccess` file with below rules in your includes directory you want to forbid access to. These rules allow only `$_POST` requests on files contained in the directory as well as you can include one file to another restricting the direct access to that include file.

```
<LimitExcept POST>
order deny,allow
deny from all
</LimitExcept>
```

Comment: Much appreciated answer. With aid from Magnus Eriksson, I sorted my issue, but I'm sure this will come in handy for future questions similar to this. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to know that you sorted it out :)

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments to the original question by Magnus Eriksson, to achieve the effect that I wanted to with CSS files, JS files, and other resource files is something that cannot be done, as these files are directly fetched by the HTML, and therefore use http requests.

The PHP files however are able to be protected, by placing a .htaccess file in the `/framework/` directory with the content of:

```
deny from all
```

To grant access to the resource's in `/framework/assets/`, All that needed to be done was to add another .htaccess file with `allow from all` written inside.

Simple answer to a simple question.

Documentation for further use:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html